# I have to change class using script, html,css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I gave class to div as `col-sm-10`. But on click, I want that class to be `col-sm-12` of that div. I mean, I want it to be responsive

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "15%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #4682B4;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.table {
  border: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 7%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" style="font-size:16px;color:white"></i></a>

      <div class="menus">
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <a href="#">Clients</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>

  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Sr No.</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Picture</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>Picture</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>Picture</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>Picture</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

on page load div `col-sm-10` would be `col-sm-12` and in `openNav()` function I want it to be again `col-sm-10` and viceversa

can anybody help me out with the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet that should do what you want using only (vanilla) Javascript.
I've added the variable affectations at the beginning, and one line to change the `className` in both of your functions:

(I also added FontAwesome and some styling to make the snippet effect visual.)

```js
var mySidenav = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
var table = document.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-10")[0];

function openNav() {
  mySidenav.style.width = "15%";
  // Solution to toggle between classes
  table.classList.add('col-sm-12');
  table.classList.remove('col-sm-10');
}

function closeNav() {
  mySidenav.style.width = "0";
  // Solution when you can replace all the class='…' string
  table.className = 'col-sm-10';
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #4682B4;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.table {
  border: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 7%;
}


/* Added to make it visual */
.col-sm-10,
.col-sm-12 {
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.col-sm-12 {
  margin-left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" style="font-size:16px;color:white"></i></a>

      <div class="menus">
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <a href="#">Clients</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>

  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Sr No.</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Picture</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>Picture</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>Picture</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>Picture</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".col-sm-10").click(function(){
    $(".col-sm-10").addClass("col-sm-12").removeClass('col-sm-10');
    alert('class changed')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-2">
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" style="font-size:16px;color:white"></i></a>
    
    <div class="menus">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
   <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
   
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-10"> 
   <table class="table">  
      <tr>
       <th>Sr No.</th>
       <th>Title</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Picture</th>
       <th>Action</th>
       <th>Picture</th>
       <th>Action</th>
       <th>Picture</th>
       <th>Action</th>
       <th>Picture</th>
       <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
   </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

HOPE this make sense to you how to change class

Answer (score -1):

you can add class by

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("selector").addClass("class_name");
});
```

And to remove class, use

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("selector").removeClass("class_name");
});
```

For futher information you can visit
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_addclass.asp

Comment: There is no jQuery in the question.